# Generating the SQL Sequence Numbers(Row_Numbers) based on the 10-Days Filters

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2016, recursive-query

```
Customer_Id        Call_Date             Agent_M_Code    Row_Indicator
 810471698    2020-03-19 13:25:24.910       rmanzan2           1
 810471698    2020-03-22 20:28:19.067       pmaclair           2
 810471698    2020-03-24 09:22:47.833       njeanle            3
 810471698    2020-03-24 12:36:29.367       edelaro4           4
 810471698    2020-03-29 22:36:29.762       kdularo7           1
 810471698    2020-04-11 11:21:11.243       rbustam1           1
 810471698    2020-04-11 17:50:41.023       frenteri           2
 810471698    2020-05-10 11:16:21.683       cschuch2           1
 810471698    2020-05-13 15:26:40.660       gledesma           2
 810471698    2020-07-03 11:26:20.697       cmataver           1
 810471698    2020-07-22 14:19:53.450       irodri13           1
 980471627    2020-07-21 14:00:45.923       jgalind8           1
 980471627    2020-07-21 14:04:42.277       jabne              2
 980471627    2020-07-21 14:06:33.627       abyerley           3
 980471627    2020-07-10 07:11:31.817       rbustam1           1
 980471627    2020-03-15 22:36:29.763       cmanalot           1
 966615610    2020-06-18 17:50:41.023       lmendiza           1
 966615610    2020-06-22 14:19:53.450       melli17            2
 966615610    2020-01-03 11:16:21.683       gledesma           1
 966615610    2020-01-07 15:26:40.660       vchapa1            2
 966615610    2020-01-21 11:26:20.697       amanriq1           1
```

For the above table i need to generate the row_indicators based on the customer_Id but the condition here is... if the above Call_Date and below call_Date in between 10 Days then we need to generate the row_indicator in sequence i.e, (1,2,3,4..) if not again we need to start with 1.

I have tried with LEAD() function and i generated the row_number() partition by Customer_Id but it didn't work out.

**For Example:**
In the above example table the first four rows are in between 10 days (Less than or equal to 240 Hrs) then for the first four rows the row_indicators are 1,2,3,4 and again from the fifth row the Call_Date is started from 1 because the fifth row date is not falling in the 10 days Call_Date range.

Kindly any help me with an T-SQL script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a recursive query:

```
with 
    data (select t.*, row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by call_date) rn,
    cte as (
        select d.*, call_date ref_call_date
        from data
        where rn = 1
        union all
        select d.*, case when d.call_date > dateadd(day, 10, c.ref_call_date) then d.call_date else c.ref_call_date end
        from cte c
        inner join data d on d.customer_id = c.customer_id and d.rn = c.rn + 1
    )
select 
    c.*, 
    row_number() over(partition by customer_id, ref_call_date order by call_date) new_row_indicator  
from cte c
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ddfec36614ec774d9e7c609f47d1c2c4)**

> 

```
Customer_Id | Call_Date               | Agent_M_Code | Row_Indicator | rn | ref_call_date           | new_row_indicator
----------: | :---------------------- | :----------- | ------------: | -: | :---------------------- | ----------------:
  966615610 | 2020-01-03 11:16:21.683 | gledesma     |             1 |  1 | 2020-01-03 11:16:21.683 |                 1
  966615610 | 2020-01-07 15:26:40.660 | vchapa1      |             2 |  2 | 2020-01-03 11:16:21.683 |                 2
  966615610 | 2020-01-21 11:26:20.697 | amanriq1     |             1 |  3 | 2020-01-21 11:26:20.697 |                 1
  980471627 | 2020-03-15 22:36:29.763 | cmanalot     |             1 |  1 | 2020-03-15 22:36:29.763 |                 1
  810471698 | 2020-03-19 13:25:24.910 | rmanzan2     |             1 |  1 | 2020-03-19 13:25:24.910 |                 1
  810471698 | 2020-03-22 20:28:19.067 | pmaclair     |             2 |  2 | 2020-03-19 13:25:24.910 |                 2
  810471698 | 2020-03-24 09:22:47.833 | njeanle      |             3 |  3 | 2020-03-19 13:25:24.910 |                 3
  810471698 | 2020-03-24 12:36:29.367 | edelaro4     |             4 |  4 | 2020-03-19 13:25:24.910 |                 4
  810471698 | 2020-03-29 22:36:29.763 | kdularo7     |             1 |  5 | 2020-03-29 22:36:29.763 |                 1
  810471698 | 2020-04-11 11:21:11.243 | rbustam1     |             1 |  6 | 2020-04-11 11:21:11.243 |                 1
  810471698 | 2020-04-11 17:50:41.023 | frenteri     |             2 |  7 | 2020-04-11 11:21:11.243 |                 2
  810471698 | 2020-05-10 11:16:21.683 | cschuch2     |             1 |  8 | 2020-05-10 11:16:21.683 |                 1
  810471698 | 2020-05-13 15:26:40.660 | gledesma     |             2 |  9 | 2020-05-10 11:16:21.683 |                 2
  966615610 | 2020-06-18 17:50:41.023 | lmendiza     |             1 |  4 | 2020-06-18 17:50:41.023 |                 1
  966615610 | 2020-06-22 14:19:53.450 | melli17      |             2 |  5 | 2020-06-18 17:50:41.023 |                 2
  810471698 | 2020-07-03 11:26:20.697 | cmataver     |             1 | 10 | 2020-07-03 11:26:20.697 |                 1
  980471627 | 2020-07-10 07:11:31.817 | rbustam1     |             1 |  2 | 2020-07-10 07:11:31.817 |                 1
  980471627 | 2020-07-21 14:00:45.923 | jgalind8     |             1 |  3 | 2020-07-21 14:00:45.923 |                 1
  980471627 | 2020-07-21 14:04:42.277 | jabne        |             2 |  4 | 2020-07-21 14:00:45.923 |                 2
  980471627 | 2020-07-21 14:06:33.627 | abyerley     |             3 |  5 | 2020-07-21 14:00:45.923 |                 3
  810471698 | 2020-07-22 14:19:53.450 | irodri13     |             1 | 11 | 2020-07-22 14:19:53.450 |                 1
```

Comment: I have more records in my table(around 15-lacks records) by using this solution my SQL Server is going under maximum recursion stage. Could you please suggest me an another solution which i can implement on huge data.

Comment: @Madhavenugopal: you need to add this at the very end of the query: `option(maxrecursion 0)`.

Comment: I have tried with option(maxrecursion 0).... but i am getting the duplicates ref_call_date for the customers (customer_id). Could you please suggest me an alternative approach

Comment: @Madhavenugopal: I fixed a few typos in the query and tested it against your sample data: this does produce the results that you expect, as you can see in the above db fiddle by compaing column `Row_Indicator` (your data) with `new_row_indicator` (the results of the query).

Comment: Thanks for your time and support... Your code is working as expected for the 2 Days difference and 10 Days difference .. It's helps me a lot @GMB.

I got the good solution ....

Answer (score 1):

It could be done without recursion using integer division of the date differences between the earliest call date and the call dates.

Data (not complete)

```
drop table if exists #call_data;
go
select * INTO #call_data from (values 
('810471698', '2020-03-19 13:25:24.910', 'rmanzan2'),
('810471698', '2020-03-22 20:28:19.067', 'rmanzan2'),
('810471698', '2020-03-24 09:22:47.833', 'rmanzan2'),
('810471698', '2020-03-24 12:36:29.367', 'rmanzan2'),
('810471698', '2020-03-29 22:36:29.762', 'rmanzan2'),
('810471698', '2020-04-11 11:21:11.243', 'rmanzan2'),
('980471627', '2020-07-21 14:00:45.923', 'rmanzan2'),
('980471627', '2020-07-21 14:04:42.277', 'rmanzan2'),
('980471627', '2020-07-21 14:06:33.627', 'rmanzan2'),
('966615610', '2020-06-18 17:50:41.023', 'rmanzan2'),
('966615610', '2020-01-21 11:26:20.697', 'rmanzan2')) V(customer_id, call_date, Agent_M_Code);
```

Query

```
;with
rn_cte(customer_id, call_date, Agent_M_Code, rn) as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by call_date) rn
    from #call_data),
grp_cte(customer_id, call_date, Agent_M_Code, day_diff_grp) as (
    select cd.customer_id, cd.call_date, cd.Agent_M_Code, datediff(d, rn.call_date, cd.call_date)/10
    from #call_data cd
         left join rn_cte rn on cd.customer_id=rn.customer_id
    where rn.rn=1)
select *, row_number() over (partition by customer_id, day_diff_grp order by call_date) row_indicator
from grp_cte
order by 1, 2;
```

Output

```
customer_id call_date   Agent_M_Code    day_diff_grp    row_indicator
810471698   2020-03-19 13:25:24.910 rmanzan2    0   1
810471698   2020-03-22 20:28:19.067 rmanzan2    0   2
810471698   2020-03-24 09:22:47.833 rmanzan2    0   3
810471698   2020-03-24 12:36:29.367 rmanzan2    0   4
810471698   2020-03-29 22:36:29.762 rmanzan2    1   1
810471698   2020-04-11 11:21:11.243 rmanzan2    2   1
966615610   2020-01-21 11:26:20.697 rmanzan2    0   1
966615610   2020-06-18 17:50:41.023 rmanzan2    14  1
980471627   2020-07-21 14:00:45.923 rmanzan2    0   1
980471627   2020-07-21 14:04:42.277 rmanzan2    0   2
980471627   2020-07-21 14:06:33.627 rmanzan2    0   3
```

[EDIT] Changed the code to a 2 day rolling window:

```
;with
rn_cte(customer_id, call_date, Agent_M_Code, rn) as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by call_date) rn
    from #call_data),
grp_cte(customer_id, call_date, Agent_M_Code, day_diff_grp) as (
    select cd.customer_id, cd.call_date, cd.Agent_M_Code, datediff(d, rn.call_date, cd.call_date)/2
    from #call_data cd
         left join rn_cte rn on cd.customer_id=rn.customer_id
    where rn.rn=1)
select *, row_number() over (partition by customer_id, day_diff_grp order by call_date) row_indicator
from grp_cte
order by 1, 2;
```

Output

```
customer_id call_date   Agent_M_Code    day_diff_grp    row_indicator
810471698   2020-03-19 13:25:24.910 rmanzan2    0   1
810471698   2020-03-22 20:28:19.067 rmanzan2    1   1
810471698   2020-03-24 09:22:47.833 rmanzan2    2   1
810471698   2020-03-24 12:36:29.367 rmanzan2    2   2
810471698   2020-03-29 22:36:29.762 rmanzan2    5   1
810471698   2020-04-11 11:21:11.243 rmanzan2    11  1
966615610   2020-01-21 11:26:20.697 rmanzan2    0   1
966615610   2020-06-18 17:50:41.023 rmanzan2    74  1
980471627   2020-07-21 14:00:45.923 rmanzan2    0   1
980471627   2020-07-21 14:04:42.277 rmanzan2    0   2
980471627   2020-07-21 14:06:33.627 rmanzan2    0   3
```

[EDIT] Changed to a 240 hour rolling window

```
;with
rn_cte(customer_id, call_date, Agent_M_Code, rn) as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by call_date) rn
    from #call_data),
grp_cte(customer_id, call_date, Agent_M_Code, day_diff_grp) as (
    select cd.customer_id, cd.call_date, cd.Agent_M_Code, datediff(hour, rn.call_date, cd.call_date)/240
    from #call_data cd
         left join rn_cte rn on cd.customer_id=rn.customer_id
    where rn.rn=1)
select *, row_number() over (partition by customer_id, day_diff_grp order by call_date) row_indicator
from grp_cte
order by 1, 2;
```

Output

```
customer_id call_date   Agent_M_Code    day_diff_grp    row_indicator
810471698   2020-03-19 13:25:24.910 rmanzan2    0   1
810471698   2020-03-22 20:28:19.067 rmanzan2    0   2
810471698   2020-03-24 09:22:47.833 rmanzan2    0   3
810471698   2020-03-24 12:36:29.367 rmanzan2    0   4
810471698   2020-03-29 22:36:29.762 rmanzan2    1   1
810471698   2020-04-11 11:21:11.243 rmanzan2    2   1
966615610   2020-01-21 11:26:20.697 rmanzan2    0   1
966615610   2020-06-18 17:50:41.023 rmanzan2    14  1
980471627   2020-07-21 14:00:45.923 rmanzan2    0   1
980471627   2020-07-21 14:04:42.277 rmanzan2    0   2
980471627   2020-07-21 14:06:33.627 rmanzan2    0   3
```

Comment: The above code is working fine for 10 Days difference (Less than or equal to 240 Hrs)...But when i am trying to implement the same logic for 2 Days difference i.e, (Less than or equal to 48 Hrs) it's not working...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I have tried with CASE Statements With Self Joins but it didn't work out...Could you please suggest me the solution for this.

Comment: 2 day and 240 hour windows were added

Comment: I have tried with the both conditions datediff(d, rn.call_date, cd.call_date)/2 & datediff(hour, rn.call_date, cd.call_date)/240... but the row_indicators are generating as unexpected
**FOR EXAMPLE** While generating the row_indicators we need to check the above call_date & below call_date...if the above call_date & below call_date is lesser than or equal to 240 Hours then the row_indicators should be in sequence (1,2,3...) if not again it needs to start with 1.
**EXAMPLE-DATA**
810471698 2020-03-22 20:28:19.067 rmanzan2  1
810471698 2020-03-24 09:22:47.833 rmanzan2  2